# Relational operations using only increment, loop, assign, zero

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, equality, lambda-calculus

This is a follow up question for: [Subtraction operation using only increment, loop, assign, zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34078233/783743)

We're only allowed to use the following operations:

1. incr(x) - Once this function is called it will assign x + 1 to x
2. assign(x, y) - This function will assign the value of y to x (x = y)
3. zero(x) - This function will assign 0 to x (x = 0)
4. loop X { } - operations written within brackets will be executed X times

For example, addition can be implemented as follows:

```
add(x, y) {
    loop x
        { y = incr(y) }
    return y
}
```

How do I implement the [relational operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_operator) using these four operations? The relational operations are:

1. eq(x, y) - Is x equal to y?
2. lt(x, y) - Is x lesser than y?
3. gt(x, y) - Is x greater than y?

We also have their opposites:

1. ne(x, y) - Is x not equal to y?
2. gte(x, y) - Is x greater than or equal to y?
3. lte(x, y) - Is x lesser than or equal to y?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you'd be interested in learning about the [Lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) and [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding). Your question is directly answered in these two articles.

Comment: You should accept my answer if it solved your problem. Click on the tick mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The set of natural numbers `N` is closed under addition and subtraction:

```
N + N = N
N - N = N
```

This means that the addition or subtraction of two natural numbers is also a natural number (considering `0 - 1` is `0` and not `-1`, we can't have negative natural numbers).

However, the set of natural numbers `N` is not closed under relational operations:

```
N < N = {0, 1}
N > N = {0, 1}
```

This means that the result of comparing two natural numbers is either truthfulness (i.e. `1`) or falsehood (i.e. `0`).

So, we treat the set of booleans (i.e. `{0, 1}`) as a restricted set of the natural numbers (i.e. `N`).

```
false = 0
true  = incr(false)
```

The first question we must answer is “how do we encode `if` statements so that we may branch based on either truthfulness or falsehood?” The answer is simple, we use the `loop` operation:

```
isZero(x) {
    y = true
    loop x { y = false }
    return y
}
```

If the loop condition is `true` (i.e. `1`) then the loop executes exactly once. If the loop condition is `false` (i.e. `0`) then the loop doesn't execute. We can use this to write branching code.

So, how do we define the relational operations? Turns out, everything can be defined in terms of `lte`:

```
lte(x, y) {
    z = sub(x, y)
    z = isZero(z)
    return z
}
```

We know that `x ≥ y` is the same as `y ≤ x`. Therefore:

```
gte(x, y) {
    z = lte(y, x)
    return z
}
```

We know that if `x > y` is true then `x ≤ y` is false. Therefore:

```
gt(x, y) {
    z = lte(x, y)
    z = not(z)
    return z
}
```

We know that `x < y` is the same as `y > x`. Therefore:

```
lt(x, y) {
    z = gt(y, x)
    return z
}
```

We know that if `x ≤ y` and `y ≤ x` then `x = y`. Therefore:

```
eq(x, y) {
    l = lte(x, y)
    r = lte(y, x)
    z = and(l, r)
    return z
}
```

Finally, we know that if `x = y` is true then `x ≠ y` is false. Therefore:

```
ne(x, y) {
    z = eq(x, y)
    z = not(z)
    return z
}
```

Now, all we need to do is define the following functions:

1. The `sub` function is defined as follows:

   ```
   sub(x, y) {
       loop y
           { x = decr(x) }
       return x
   }

   decr(x) {
       y = 0
       z = 0

       loop x {
           y = z
           z = incr(z)
       }

       return y
   }
   ```
2. The `not` function is the same as the `isZero` function:

   ```
   not(x) {
       y = isZero(x)
       return y
   }
   ```
3. The `and` function is the same as the `mul` function:

   ```
   and(x, y) {
       z = mul(x, y)
       return z
   }

   mul(x, y) {
       z = 0
       loop x { z = add(y, z) }
       return z
   }

   add(x, y) {
       loop x
           { y = incr(y) }
       return y
   }
   ```

That's all you need. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aadit.Interesting

Comment: Very nicely explained.

Comment: Thank you @LeandroCaniglia.