# Divide operation using increment, loop, assign, zero

Tags: algorithm, math, logic

We're only allowed to use the following operations:

`incr(x)` - Once this function is called it will assign x + 1 to x

`assign(x, y)` - This function will assign the value of y to x (x = y)

`zero(x)` - This function will assign 0 to x (x = 0)

`loop X { }` - operations written within brackets will be executed X times

How can I implement divide operation?

Comment: Can I use conditionals?

Comment: @HectorDavila No, but you can implement conditionals using the aforementioned operations as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34829670/783743

Comment: That sounds like a homework question. Can you show your attempts so far?

Comment: Are the numbers (input and output) integers? for `div(x,y)` can I assume `x>=y`?

Comment: @A.Sarid The numbers are non-negative integers and you can't assume that `x` is greater than `y`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Sarid's answer is correct, it's possible to compute `floor(x / y)` more efficiently as follows:

```js
divide(x, y) {
    x = incr(x)

    z = 0

    loop x {
        x = sub(x, y)
        l = isTrue(x)
        z = add(z, l)
    }

    return z
}
```

The `add` and `sub` functions have been previously defined here:

[Subtraction operation using only increment, loop, assign, zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34078233/783743)

The `isTrue` function is defined as follows:

```js
isTrue(x) {
    y = false
    loop x { y = true }
    return y
}
```

Note that we've previously defined `true` and `false` as follows:

```js
false = 0
true  = incr(false)
```

The only problem with this function is that `divide(n, 0)` returns `n + 1` instead of an error.

Comment: Yes, this is another nice way for implementing floor. I guess there are many ways you can implement it. I've added another way to my answer as well. :)

Answer (score 2):

This question combines two other posts that were already answered in SO:

1. [Relational operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34829670/relational-operations-using-only-increment-loop-assign-zero?lq=1)
2. [Subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078233/subtraction-operation-using-only-increment-loop-assign-zero)

From these questions we can see how to implement `sub(x,y)` , `gt(x,y)` , `lte(x,t)` and `add(x,y)`.
By using those, we can implement the divide operation - both `ceil(x/y)` and `floor(x/y)`:

### Ceil(x/y)

```
div_ceil(x,y){
    r = 0
    loop x{
        z = 0
        l = gt(x,z)
        r = add(r,l)
        x = sub(x,y)
    }
    return r
}
```

**Explanation:**
We loop x times and each time we subtract `y` from `x` and we count the number of times it takes until `x` no longer greater than `0`. When it is greater than `0` we add `1` to our result.

Why is the loop running `x` times?
Because it is the maximum needed times in order to get to the result. This is given when `y == 1`, subtracting `1` `x` times - we will get `r == x`.

---

### Floor(x/y)

```
div_floor(x,y){ 
    r = 0
    t = 0
    loop x{
        t = add(t,y)
        l = lte(t,x)
        r = add(r,l)
    }
    return r
}
```

Or, if you want, by simply using `div_ceil` method above we can also get `floor(x/y)`:

```
div_floor(x,y){
    z = div_ceil(x,y)
    k = div_ceil(incr(x),y)
    l = eq(z,k)
    z = sub(z,l)
    return z
}
```

Simply comparing the results of `x/y` and `x+1/y`. If they are equal meaning we did a round up (ceiling) in `dev(x,y)` so we need to subtract `1` to get the floor result. If they are not equal, the results should stay the same.

---

### Testing & Notes

Please see the correctness of these methods [running live here](http://ideone.com/7zSilY).
I implemented all functions in C++ so they will behave exactly the same (by using only allowed operations).

I assumed that dividing by `0` is an undefined behavior. Those methods will return some value instead of an error in case of `y==0`.

Comment: Isn't calculating ceiling of the result? I mean that it calculates reminder as +1? sub(2, 4) will return 0 anyway.

Comment: Let's verify it with `div(6,4)`. The second subtraction will be `sub(2,4)` which gives `0`. So `r == 2` at the end. I that case it's `ceiling(x/y)`. Am I right?

Comment: @AaditMShah that's true - `loop x` is a static assignment

Comment: @A.Sarid I think the solution is incorrect - `sub(x, y)` where `x < y` will always return `0` which means `gte(x,0)` will return `1` and then we increment `r`.

Comment: @A.Sarid I think it's `floor(x/y)` which is actually the desirable result.

Comment: @user2327475 You can also get the floor using this method. See my edit.

Comment: @user2327475 It's possible to compute `floor(x / y)` more efficiently. See my updated answer.

Comment: @user2327475 I've done another update to my answer. Added an implementation for `floor(x/y)` that does not use the ceiling method. In addition, I've added a live test to check for correctness. See the *Testing* section.